# Why are brackets required to print type information of .?

Tags: haskell, syntax, parse-error

To print the type information of `.` I use :

```
λ> :type (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

If I omit the brackets , causes an error :

```
λ> :type .
<interactive>:1:1: parse error on input ‘.’
```

The same is not true for other types :

```
λ> :type 1
1 :: Num a => a
λ> :type (1)
(1) :: Num a => a
λ> :type True 
True :: Bool
λ> :type (True)
(True) :: Bool
```

Why the special behavior for `.` ?

Comment: That's true for all operators. It's just a parsing thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` without the parentheses only works in infix position. `:t` however takes an expression, e.g. a function, and to turn an infix operator symbol into an expression, you need to surround it with parens.

Consider:

```
3 + 4 = (+) 3 4  -- pseudocode
```

and

```
myPlus = (+)
```

which is the same as

```
myPlus a b = a + b
myPlus a b = (+) a b
```

And it applies equally to all other infix operators such as `*` or `>>=` or `&&&` etc.